# Корень в словах ТЫ, ВЫ

Tags: морфемика

Олимпиадное задание по русскому языку: найти корни в словах ТЫ, ВЫ. Ответ: корень - всё слово, то есть ТЫ, ВЫ. Арументируют ответ словами "тыкать, выкать". 
Тогда как быть с формами ТЕБЯ? ТОБОЙ? ВАМИ? ВАС? Какой же корень в этих словах на самом деле? Интересно ваше мнение. Спасибо!

Comment: Я согласен с ответом данном на олимпиаде. В современном употреблении некорректно  выделять составной корень. Корень здесь вся основа слова, т.е. ты, вы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл [вот такой ответ](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/). Похоже на истину.
Со словом "ты" - картина [аналогичная](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/).

Comment: Да, это уже кое-что! Спасибо! А я не догадалась формы поискать-посмотреть.

Comment: Корень явно "нестандартный". Первое предположение - "основная форма" не является "исходной".. Труднее было найти.

Answer (score 1):

Корни "Т" и "В". Так же, возможно, должен быть рудиментарный знак вроде: Т' и В'

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что корни в этих словах - Т и В

Answer (score 0):

В Грамматике-80 приводится склонение местоимений: ты - теб/я - теб/е - тоб/ой - о теб/е, вы - в/ас - в/ам - в/ами - о в/ас.

Таким образом, в начальной форме основа "ты, вы", а в косвенных падежах - "теб-/тоб- и в-.